# How to video Record a Part of Activity?

Tags: android, video, screen, media, recording

I want to record a part of the activity of my android application.
(The rectangular area with a 10dp padding from activity border)

The output should be a video with the audio spoken during the recording time.

Conditions
- No Root should be required
- No Screen Recording Permission

Example App:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.unacademy

Can anyone help?

I have tried Media Projection API in Android Version 21 but it records the full screen and also popups the user that I am trying to record full screen.